# Simple game with pygame , cleanup code + game over screen

Tags: python, pygame, code-cleanup

this is my first post written here. With several tutorials and some advices got from here I created simple game.
Could someone please take a look on the code? Is there a better way to structure these function?
I know it looks messy but at least its working ;)
As it is my first game I really enjoy it. Here is my code
code in game.py file :

```
import sys

import pygame

from rocket import Rocket


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # configuration
        self.tps_max = 100.0
        # initialization
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.tps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.tps_delta = 0.0
        self.player = Rocket(self)
        game = True
        while game is True:
            # Handle events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit(0)

            # ticking
            self.tps_delta += self.tps_clock.tick() / 1000.0
            while self.tps_delta > 1 / self.tps_max:
                self.tick()
                self.tps_delta -= 1 / self.tps_max

            # drawing
            self.screen.fill((164, 222, 245))
            self.draw()
            pygame.display.flip()

    def tick(self):
        # check input
        self.player.tick()

    def draw(self):
        self.player.draw()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game()
```

Code in Rocket.py file:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys

from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)


class Rocket(object):

    def __init__(self, game):

        self.game_over = False
        self.game = game
        size = self.game.screen.get_size()

        self.speed = 3.0
        self.wind_force = 0.2
        self.wind_angle = random.randint(0, 359)
        self.current_force = 0.1
        self.current_angle = random.randint(0, 359)
        self.random_change = 0
        self.pos = Vector2(size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2)

        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.acc = Vector2(0, 0)
        # heading vector

        self.heading = self.vel.angle_to(Vector2(0, 1))
        self.angle_speed = 0

    def addforce(self, force):
        self.acc += force

    def tick(self):
        # Input
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, -self.speed * 0.6).rotate(self.heading))
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading))
            # self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed))
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading - 90))
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading + 90))
        if pressed[pygame.K_q]:
            self.angle_speed -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_e]:
            self.angle_speed += 1
        # Physics

        self.wind_angle = (self.wind_angle + random.randint(-2, 2)) % 360
        self.wind_force += ((random.randint(-1, 2)) / 1000)

        self.current_angle = (self.current_angle + 0.1 * random.randint(-1, 1)) % 360
        self.current_force += ((random.randint(-1, 2)) / 1000)

        self.vel *= 0.5
        self.vel += Vector2(0, self.wind_force).rotate(self.wind_angle)
        self.vel += Vector2(0, self.current_force).rotate(self.current_angle)
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.acc *= 0.5
        self.angle_speed *= 0.5

        self.heading = (self.heading + self.angle_speed) % 360
        # offset
        # check distance from centre to vessel pos
        self.offset = math.hypot(((self.vel[0] - self.pos[0]) + 640), ((self.vel[1] - self.pos[1]) + 360))
        # offset as 1
        self.offset /= 750
        # offset as accuracy in %
        self.offset = int((1 - self.offset) * 100)
        # gamer over to do
        if self.offset < 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            pass

    def draw(self):

        # base shape
        vessel = [Vector2(5, 10), Vector2(-5, 10), Vector2(-5, -10), Vector2(0, -15), Vector2(5, -10)]
        wind_arrow = [Vector2(0, 10), Vector2(0, 20), Vector2(20, 20), Vector2(20, 30), Vector2(30, 15), Vector2(20, 0),
                      Vector2(20, 10)]
        current_arrow = [Vector2(0, 10), Vector2(0, 20), Vector2(20, 20), Vector2(20, 30), Vector2(30, 15),
                         Vector2(20, 0),
                         Vector2(20, 10)]

        # rotating points

        vessel = [p.rotate(self.heading) for p in vessel]
        wind_arrow = [p.rotate(self.wind_angle + 90) for p in wind_arrow]
        current_arrow = [p.rotate(self.current_angle + 90) for p in current_arrow]

        # centered position & scale
        vessel = [self.pos + p * 6 for p in vessel]
        wind_arrow = [self.pos + p for p in wind_arrow]
        current_arrow = [self.pos + p for p in current_arrow]
        # draw shape
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (255, 177, 10), vessel)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (233, 66, 245), wind_arrow)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (22, 57, 217), current_arrow)

        def write(text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
            self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)

        write(" Accuracy:" + str(self.offset), (20, 10))
        write('Wind direction: ' + str(round(self.wind_angle)) + "deg . Wind force: " + str(
            round((self.wind_force * 10), 2)), (20, 40))
        write('Current direction: ' + str(round(self.current_angle)) + "deg . Current force: " + str(
            round(self.current_force, 2)),
              (20, 60))

        # def writegameover(text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        #     self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)
        #     if self.game_over:
        #         writegameover(" GAME OVER", (200, 100))
```

I am pretty happy what I have, that was easier than I expected. More less I understand all the code. I am able to do minor modification, but I know my game is far away from being perfect.
Beside cleaning and optimalization, issue I can not handle is Game Over screen.
I don't know where place game_over method(). For now I have just set to quit game when game_over  condition is met, but I want to display some game over screen with question "play again?" with some score. I know the best solution would be implement states Running, reset, game_over etc but its too complicated for me.
Could you please help me with this? Again, please understand this is my first python application, so any advices from you guys will be appreciated.

---

after some modification my rocket.py file still does not show Game over subtitle:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys

from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)

class Rocket(object):

    def __init__(self, game):

        self.game_over = False
        self.game = game
        size = self.game.screen.get_size()

        self.speed = 3.0
        self.wind_force = 0.2
        self.wind_angle = random.randint(0, 359)
        self.current_force = 0.1
        self.current_angle = random.randint(0, 359)
        self.random_change = 0
        self.pos = Vector2(size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2)

        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.acc = Vector2(0, 0)
        # heading vector

        self.heading = self.vel.angle_to(Vector2(0, 1))
        self.angle_speed = 0

    def addforce(self, force):
        self.acc += force

    def tick(self):
        # Input
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, -self.speed * 0.6).rotate(self.heading))
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading))
            # self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed))
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading - 90))
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            self.addforce(Vector2(0, self.speed * 0.3).rotate(self.heading + 90))
        if pressed[pygame.K_q]:
            self.angle_speed -= 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_e]:
            self.angle_speed += 1
        # Physics

        self.wind_angle = (self.wind_angle + random.randint(-2, 2)) % 360
        self.wind_force += ((random.randint(-1, 2)) / 1000)

        self.current_angle = (self.current_angle + 0.1 * random.randint(-1, 1)) % 360
        self.current_force += ((random.randint(-1, 2)) / 1000)

        self.vel *= 0.5
        self.vel += Vector2(0, self.wind_force).rotate(self.wind_angle)
        self.vel += Vector2(0, self.current_force).rotate(self.current_angle)
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.acc *= 0.5
        self.angle_speed *= 0.5

        self.heading = (self.heading + self.angle_speed) % 360
        # offset
        # check distance from centre to vessel pos
        self.offset = math.hypot(((self.vel[0] - self.pos[0]) + 640), ((self.vel[1] - self.pos[1]) + 360))
        # offset as 1
        self.offset /= 750
        # offset as accuracy in %
        self.offset = int((1 - self.offset) * 100)
        # gamer over to do
        if self.offset < 0:
         #    sys.exit(0)

            self.writegameover(" GAME OVER:", (200, 100))
        else:
            pass

    def draw(self):

        # base shape
        vessel = [Vector2(5, 10), Vector2(-5, 10), Vector2(-5, -10), Vector2(0, -15), Vector2(5, -10)]
        wind_arrow = [Vector2(0, 10), Vector2(0, 20), Vector2(20, 20), Vector2(20, 30), Vector2(30, 15), Vector2(20, 0),
                      Vector2(20, 10)]
        current_arrow = [Vector2(0, 10), Vector2(0, 20), Vector2(20, 20), Vector2(20, 30), Vector2(30, 15),
                         Vector2(20, 0),
                         Vector2(20, 10)]

        # rotating points

        vessel = [p.rotate(self.heading) for p in vessel]
        wind_arrow = [p.rotate(self.wind_angle + 90) for p in wind_arrow]
        current_arrow = [p.rotate(self.current_angle + 90) for p in current_arrow]

        # centered position & scale
        vessel = [self.pos + p * 6 for p in vessel]
        wind_arrow = [self.pos + p for p in wind_arrow]
        current_arrow = [self.pos + p for p in current_arrow]
        # draw shape
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (255, 177, 10), vessel)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (233, 66, 245), wind_arrow)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.game.screen, (22, 57, 217), current_arrow)

        def write(text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
            self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)

        write(" Accuracy:" + str(self.offset), (20, 10))
        write('Wind direction: ' + str(round(self.wind_angle)) + "deg . Wind force: " + str(
            round((self.wind_force * 10), 2)), (20, 40))
        write('Current direction: ' + str(round(self.current_angle)) + "deg . Current force: " + str(
            round(self.current_force, 2)),
              (20, 60))

    def writegameover(self, text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)
```

Comment: Hi Dan3el, welcome!! I'm glad you got some answers here, but for the future I thought I'd recommend a different way to post here, to maximize the chance that you get good answers. Try directly addressing the question right in the title or the first sentence. The background is nice, but if people have to read through a lot of background they might not. I suggest saying something like, "Is there a better way to structure these function" right at the very beginning. Anyways, I hope that helps you in the future. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can call `writegameover()` like this:

```
if self.offset < 0:
    # sys.exit(0)
    self.writegameover('GAME OVER', (200, 100), (0, 0, 0))
```

And then head down after the `write()` method

```
def writegameover(self, text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
    # self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)
    print('over')
```

Note that the indentation of the `writegameover()` method should be the same as your `draw()` method

You will see now that when you go off the boundaries your program will print over continuously

Also I'm interested to know what's the goal of the game. Should I follow the blue or the pink arrow

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your suggestion. Point of game is to stay as close to centre of screen for as long as possible. for some reasons write function doesnt work, so you can not see now wind, current and accuracy

Answer (score 0):

game still doesn't display GAME OVER on screen.
game over condition:

```
  if self.offset < 0:

            self.writegameover(self, "GAME OVER", (200, 100))
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            sys.exit(0)
```

writegameover function:

```
 def writegameover(self, text, location, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.game.screen.blit(font.render(text, True, color), location)
```

Time delay and exit works , for text display I get error: ValueError: invalid color argument.
If I specify color in arguments:

```
self.writegameover(self, "GAME OVER", (200, 100), (0,0,0)
```

I get:
TypeError: writegameover() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

I tried to do similiar to write function which working fine. For some reason writegameover has some issue with color.

Comment: When calling a function like that: `self.function(argument1, argument2)` you don't need to specify self as an argument